# How to get Sphinx doctest to reset the Django database after each test?

Tags: python, django, pytest, python-sphinx, doctest

[TL;DR] When using Sphinx's `make doctest`, Django models created in tests are committed to the database; how do we prevent them auto-committing or to reset the database between each test (using a similar method to `pytest`)?

## Setup

I created a basic Django application using the script:

```
python -m pip install django sphinx pytest pytest-django pytest-sphinx
django-admin startproject project_name
cd project_name
mkdir project_name/app
python manage.py startapp app project_name/app
touch pytest.ini
touch conftest.py
mkdir docs
cd docs ; sphinx-quickstart ; cd ..
```

*(Creating separate source and build directories in `sphinx-quickstart`.)*

Then:

1. Changed `project_name/app/models.py` to:

```py
"""Models for the test application."""

from django.db import models


class Animal(models.Model):
    """A django model for an animal.
    
    .. rubric: Example
    
    .. testsetup:: animal
    
        from project_name.app.models import Animal

    .. testcode:: animal
    
        frog = Animal.objects.create(name="frog")
        print( frog )
    
    .. testoutput:: animal
    
        Animal object (1)
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

2. Edited `project_name/settings.py` to add `'project_name.app'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. Edited `docs/source/conf.py` to add the lines under "Path Setup":

```py
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
django.setup()
```

and, under "General Configuration", to set:

```py
extensions = [
  "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
  "sphinx.ext.doctest",
]
```

4. Replaced `docs/source/index.rst` with:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

Project Name Documentation
==========================

.. currentmodule:: project_name.app.models

.. autoclass:: Animal
```

5. Replace `pytest.ini` with:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = project_name.settings
addopts = --doctest-modules
```

6. Replace `conftest.py` with:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def enable_db_access_for_all_tests(db):
    pass
```

7. Then run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

---

## Question

When I run `pytest`, the test in the documentation is run and passes every time; however, when I use Sphinx and run `make doctest` in the `docs` sub-directory it passes the first time and then subsequent times it fails as it will create a new `Animal` instance each time and and commits it to the database and will not re-create the database.

```
Running Sphinx v3.4.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [doctest]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
running tests...

Document: index
---------------
**********************************************************************
File "../../project_name/app/models.py", line ?, in animal
Failed example:
    frog = Animal.objects.create(name="frog")
    print( frog )
Expected:
    Animal object (1)
Got:
    Animal object (2)
**********************************************************************
```

How can I change `docs/source/conf.py` (or another appropriate script) to use a method similar to `pytest` so that the Sphinx doctest passes every time (without having to delete and re-create the database)?

*(I do not want to change the unit test in the documentation; I want to make sure the database is reset or that the data is not committed and is rolled-back after each test.)*

Comment: Not a complete answer, but how would you run pytest without Sphinx to not commit and rollback the transaction? If you have such an example, perhaps you could apply that to doctests and Sphinx?

Comment: @StevePiercy You just run `pytest` with the `pytest-django` package installed; which, I believe, is set-up to (out-of-the-box) to either use a fake DB or to turn `AUTOCOMMIT` off so that transactions are rolled-back. Sphinx uses a make file which calls `sphinx-build` which uses [`sphinx.ext.doctest`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/ext/doctest.py) that, in-turn, calls the `doctest` package.... so the solution might be to build a custom sphinx extension taking most of the code from `sphinx.ext.doctest` to calls `pytest` rather than `doctest`.

Comment: Digging more, `pytest-django` adds a fixture that [sets up the Django test environment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/59fdb49fbc380bc09bcac65de8acab767194b553/pytest_django/plugin.py#L379-L401) for use with its tests.

Answer (score 0):

The quick (and dirty) solution to this was to bypass the issue and flush the database before running the tests:

```
python ./manage.py migrate
python ./manage.py flush
./docs/make doctest
```

- The migrations are applied first, just in case the test SQLite database does not exist; then
- The database is flushed (you can use the `--no-input` flag to skip the prompt for input. However that may be dangerous if accidentally applied to a production database so its not included by default); and
- Finally, run the documentation test on the empty database.

This works in the simple example but may not provide a robust solution if there are many examples being run which create multiple instances of the same model (and would each get different auto-generated id values) and the tests are in a non-deterministic order.